# How to load an object with textures on THREE.JS?

Tags: textures, three.js

I've downloaded a house model and loaded it with THREE.OBJLoader, but I'm getting a textureless object. How do I load the textures?

[img http://o7.no/YLlkKQ](http://o7.no/YLlkKQ)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the    webgl_loader_obj_mtl    example provided in the examples folder. It shows how to load the mtl file along with the obj file.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be hitting this:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally